# NDSolve behaves worse than ParametricNDSolve in FindFit

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, fitting

I am trying to fit some model parameters to some data.

```
Ts = 0.001; duty = 0.2;
Ubat = 14; Ud = 0.6; tEnd = 0.005; Td = 8 10^-7;
pars = {R1 -> 11, L1 -> 0.01};
```

This is the RL cuircuit model driven by a PWM voltage.

```
u[t_, d_, T_, Ub_, Ud_] := If[Mod[t, T] < d T, Ub, -Ud]
eqn[R1_, L1_] = {i1'[t] == (u[t] - R1 i1[t])/L1};
ic[i01_] = {i1[0] == i01};
```

Make some noisy data.

```
times = N[Range[0, tEnd, Td 20]];
noisyData = 
Transpose[{times,sol[times] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.01], Length[times]]}];
Show[Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, tEnd}], lp = ListPlot[noisyData, PlotRange -> All,  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLegends -> {"data"}]]
```

[image]

**Than I compare the two different approches:**

With normal `NDSolve` and "memoization":

```
modelRLNDS[R1_?NumberQ,L1_?NumberQ,i01_?NumberQ]:=
modelRLNDS[R1,L1,i01]=(i1/.NDSolve[Flatten[{eqn[R1,L1]/.u[t]->u[t,duty,Ts,Ubat,Ud],ic[i01]}],i1,{t,tEnd},AccuracyGoal >10][[1]])
AbsoluteTiming[sol1=modelRLNDS[R1,L1,0.14]/.pars]
```

[image]

with `ParametricNDSolve`:

```
modelRLParaNDS=ParametricNDSolveValue[Flatten[{eqn[R1,L1]/.u[t]->u[t,duty,Ts,Ubat,Ud],ic[i01]}],i1,{t,tEnd},{R1,L1,i01},AccuracyGoal->10];
AbsoluteTiming[sol2=modelRLParaNDS[R1,L1,0.14]/.pars]
```

[image]

Both yield the same result in the same amount of time. But the models behave different in `FindFit`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Block[{count = 0}, {fit = 
    FindFit[noisyData, 
     modelRLNDS[R1, L1, i01][x], {{R1, 1}, {L1, 0.01}, {i01, 0}}, x, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> count++, AccuracyGoal -> 5], count}]]
```

[image]

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Block[{count = 0}, {fit2 = 
    FindFit[noisyData, 
     modelRLParaNDS[R1, L1, i01][x], {{R1, 1}, {L1, 0.01}, {i01, 0}}, 
     x, EvaluationMonitor :> count++, AccuracyGoal -> 5], count}]]
```

[image]

The solution with the parametric model is not only correct but it is also faster (only 6 function evaluations)!

```
Show[Plot[{modelRLNDS[R1, L1, i01][x] /. fit, 
   modelRLParaNDS[R1, L1, i01][x] /. fit2, 
   modelRLParaNDS[1, 0.1, 0][x]}, {x, 0, tEnd}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, tEnd}, {0, 0.4}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"fit1", "fit2", "starting values"}], lp]
```

[image]

Did I do something wrong with the normal `NDSolve`?

Comment: The problem with the fit is, that your model is evaluated again and again for every point `[x]`. To speed up the fit you could use "memoization": `model[R1_?NumericQ, L1_?NumericQ] := 
 model[R1, L1] = 
  i1 /. NDSolve[
     Flatten[{eqn[R1, L1] /. u[t] -> u[t, duty, Ts, Ubat, Ud], ic}], 
     i1, {t, tEnd}][[1]]`. But your fit depends strongly on the starting values ... which would be another question

Comment: Guys, please don't vote to close this question, the **update** of the question is no longer simple, see my answer for more details. BTW @ohmsweetohm I think you can clean up your question a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the **Update** of the question turns out to be interesting.

> Did I do something wrong with the normal `NDSolve`?

No, you've done nothing wrong, but you should notice the "normal `NDSolve`" approach and the `ParametricNDSolve` approach is different. `modelRLNDS` is completely a black box, while `modelRLParaNDS` isn't. For example, `modelRLParaNDS` can be used to "symbolicly" calculate the derivative of `R1`, `L1`, `i01` without difficulty:

```
D[modelRLParaNDS[R1, L1, i01][x], R1]
% /. {R1 -> 1, L1 -> 0.01, i01 -> 0}
Plot[%, {x, 0, tEnd}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

while `D[modelRLNDS[R1, L1, i01][x], R1]` cannot:

```
D[modelRLNDS[R1, L1, i01][x], R1]
% /. {R1 -> 1, L1 -> 0.01, i01 -> 0}
Plot[%, {x, 0, tEnd}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's not clearly mentioned, but the document of `Gradient` *suggests* that, when calculating gradient, `FindFit` performs symbolic differentiation if the model can be symbolically differentiated, and use finite difference if the model is a blackbox, so it's not surprising that the "normal `NDSolve`" model and the `ParametricNDSolve` model gives different fitting result. Still, `fit` can be improved, by setting **`"DifferenceOrder" -> 2`**:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Block[{count = 0}, {fit = 
    FindFit[noisyData, modelRLNDS[R1, L1, i01][x], {{R1, 1}, {L1, 0.01}, {i01, 0}}, x, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> count++, 
     Gradient -> {"FiniteDifference", "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}], count}]]
(* {0.222677, {{R1 -> 11.0405, L1 -> 0.0100116, i01 -> 0.141926}, 99}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would "memoization" of the ParmetricNDSolve model help to improve the performance?

Comment: @OhmSweetOhm I don't think so, because as far as I can tell `ParametricFunction` already owns memorization ability. (Just try e.g. `modelRLParaNDS[1, 0.02, 0]//AbsoluteTiming` twice and check the timing. )